# Can Peta Poco map to complex types?

Tags: orm, mapping, petapoco

Having 2 pocos

```
 public class ProductInfoModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public ItemInfo Producer { get; set; }
}

public class ItemInfo
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Can I do something like this?

```
var result=db.Query<ProductInfoModel>("select p.Id,p.Name,pr.Id as Producer_Id, pr.Name as Producer_Name from products p inner join producers pr on pr.Id=p.ProducerId")
```

Basically, does PetaPoco knows how to deal with Pocos containing other Poco?

I know about Experimental Multi-Poco Queries, but they seem to me pretty complicated and not quite the thing I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However this works, but no pagination support

```
var result=db.Query<ProductInfoModel,ItemInfo>(
 @"select p.Id,p.Name,pr.Id , pr.Name 
     from products p inner join producers pr on pr.Id=p.ProducerId")
```

Answer (score 2):

I reckon all you need to do is add the second type (ItemInfo) :

```
var result=db.Query<ProductInfoModel, ItemInfo>(
     "select p.Id,p.Name,pr.Id as Producer_Id, pr.Name as Producer_Name from products " +
     "p inner join producers pr on pr.Id=p.ProducerId");
```

Comment: It throws an exception about the splitting point. It seems that the column names for the nested poco have to be the same as its properties,with no hinting about the type.

Comment: That's correct, so you'll need to remove the "as Producer_Id". PetaPoco will move on to the next poco T when the next column name in the result sequence doesn't match the current poco. You can override this with the [Column] attribute on your poco properties : http://www.toptensoftware.com/Articles/75/PetaPoco-Named-Columns-Result-Columns-and-int-long-conversion